# jQuery Function to replace matching tags/keywords with a link tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need a functionality where i had to highlight/replace the matching tags/keywords  for the main text of the article and turn those matching tag/keywords into link like one shown below

`en/search.aspx?language=en-US&issue=1&pageID=2&search=Something`

Below code which i am using works fine except that it even changes HTML if it matches the keyword.

Logic for below code is simple i pass the array from code behind to jquery function in following format `"[ 'one', 'two','three','US','UK' ]"`

in this case  it will change the above link also as en-`US` matches one of the array element while looping through the contents N no of times

I would appreciate help in this regard so that function only changes the words not any matching part of word and ignore HTML tags while doing same

PART OF CODE IS IN ASP.Net Format like <%= _pPID %>;

```
function HighlightKeywords(keywords)
{        
    var el = $("#article-detail-desc");
    var language = "<%= _planguage %>";
    var pid = <%= _pPID %>;
    var issueID = <%= _pIssue %>; 

    // array format = " 'one', 'two','three','US','UK' ";

    $(keywords).each(function()
    {
        var pattern = new RegExp("("+this+")", ["gi"]);
         var rs = "<a class='ad-keyword-selected' href='en/search.aspx?Language="+language+"&PageId="+pid+"&issue="+issueID+"&search=$1' title='Seach website for:  $1'><span style='color:#990044; tex-decoration:none;'>$1</span></a>";
        el.html(el.html().replace(pattern, rs));
    });
}   

HighlightKeywords([<%= _pKeywords %>]);


<div id="article-detail-desc">

all the text related to article will be show displayed inside this div and any matching words will be replaced by the link <a></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: I use this example http://jsfiddle.net/LE3sg/3/

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string and the function woks with arrays.

Try to use:

```
// array format = ['one', 'two','three','US','UK'];
```

instead of

```
// array format = " 'one', 'two','three','US','UK' ";
```

Comment: i am using the it as `['one', 'two','three','US','UK'];`  in actual code c# return array to jQuery in correct format. problem is in the logic it replace part of ward if it matches with any array element.